# I am working on the login of an application, the authentification does not work and I have this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

> TypeError: validUser is undefined
> fakeBackend/</</<
> C:/Edutol entreprise/juma/jp-chat/frontend/src/helpers/fake-backend.js:33

code:

```
mock.onPost('/login').reply(function (config) {
    const user = JSON.parse(config['data']);
    const validUser = users.find(usr => usr.email === user.username && usr.password === user.password);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log(validUser);
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (validUser['length'] === 1) {
                resolve([200, validUser]);
            } else {
                reject({"message": "Username and password are invalid. Please enter correct username and password"});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What line is line 33? The variable appears on several lines.

I did a quick google, and found:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

> The find method executes the callbackFn function once for each index of the array until the callbackFn returns a truthy value. If so, find immediately returns the value of that element. Otherwise, find returns undefined.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: it is this line if (validUser ['length'] === 1).  I made a console.log of validUsers and it returns undefined